# EC2 retirement - Meteor / MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am hosting my Meteor Application on an Amazon EC2 instance. Today I got a mail that my instance is scheduled for retirement until the end of month. I don't have any experience with that and what are the best ways to handle the situation.

My root device type is ebs.

Amazon suggests: "We recommend that you launch replacement instances and start migrating to them."

I already created an AMI Image of my instance and launched it. Unfortunatly my app can't be reached. At the moment the instance can be reached normally via web and ssh. Is there any best practice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes there is a best practice. Ask your server administration questions on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) and not on StackOverflow since this site is for programming questions only.

Comment: The best practice is exactly what AWS states, you need to migrate to a new build of their EC cloud, for which the AMI is not valid for. I had to do the same as well for a PHP app

Comment: Sorry - I didn't know about serverfault.com. Thank you for pointing that out!